# How to output an HTML file with colored ANSI tags to console in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, terminal

I'm writing a code highlighter for fun and I want to input an HTML file full of tags/text and then spit it out to console where each different type of tag is coloured/highlighted accordingly.

I'm using nodejs on the backend and was thinking to make a regex to grab anything between `<` & `>` and saving each node type in an object with a color that is generated. Also making sure to check if the node type exist and making sure to check if the color is used already then just applying styles as I crawl, and building the object at the same time.

Is there some sort of ANSI or other library that would also help with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why I got downvoted.